# Find Determinant of A, when the Product of A and Transpose of A is Identity

Tags: determinant

If $A^T . A = I$, prove that *determinant* A = +-1.

I don't even know where to start. Can somebody please give me a good start at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\det(A)=\det(A^T)$ we have $\det(AA^T)=\det(I)=1$. This factors to $\det(A)\det(A^T)=1$ which in the real case we know means $\det(A)=\det(A^T)= \pm 1$.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand how you prove that $det(A)=det(A^T)=+-1$

Comment: Let $a=\det(A)$. We know, from [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Determinant_of_Transpose) that $\det(A)=\det(A^T)$. Then we may substitute to obtain $a^2=1$. Then we have $a=\sqrt{1}=\pm 1$.

Comment: gotcher, sorry I am kinda slow in MATHS. And its asking me to wait for 6min. I'll mark your answer as correct once the wait time over.

Comment: @TalhaTemuri Don't apologize! If you're ever confused you should ask. I tend to forget to add details.

Comment: @TalhaTemuri No problem. Thanks for asking something I've learned before ;)